# Moving objects in Tkinter canvas shows wrong # args error

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to learn more about OOP by this new Tkinter project I started. At this stage my only goal is to make a circle crossed by two lines to move in a canvas by pressing keys. So I made the visualizations of the lines and circle in this code.

```
def create_circle(circle_pos, r, canvasName, color): #center coordinates, radius
    x = int(circle_pos[0])
    y = int(circle_pos[1])
    x0 = x - r
    y0 = y - r
    x1 = x + r
    y1 = y + r
    return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill = color)

def create_lines(circle_pos, canvasName, color):
    width = canvasName["width"]
    height = canvasName["height"]
    x = int(circle_pos[0])
    y = int(circle_pos[1])

    x0 = 0
    y0 = y
    x1 = width
    y1 = y

    x2 = x
    y2 = height
    x3 = x
    y3 = 0

    canvasName.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill = color)
    canvasName.create_line(x2, y2, x3, y3, fill = color)
```

I imported that into my main code and it worked.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import visual
    from movement import movement


    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    width = 300
    height = 300

    circle_pos = [150, 150]

    canvas = Canvas(root, width = width, height = height)
    canvas.pack()

    lines = visual.create_lines(circle_pos, canvas, "gray30")
    circle = visual.create_circle(circle_pos, 5, canvas, "red2")
    m = movement(canvas, circle, lines)


    root.bind("<KeyPress-Left>",m.move_left())
    root.bind("<KeyPress-Right>",m.move_right())
    root.bind("<KeyPress-Up>",m.move_up())
    root.bind("<KeyPress-Down>",m.move_down())

    mainloop()
```

Then I created my class for moving the objects in canvas but when I ran the main program I got error:
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!canvas move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"

This is the movement code.

```
   class movement:
def __init__(self, canvasName, circle_object, lines_object):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.canvasName = canvasName
    self.circle = circle_object
    self.lines = lines_object
    self.motion()       #calling move class to move objects

def motion(self):
    self.canvasName.move(self.circle, self.x, self.y)
    self.canvasName.move(self.lines, self.x, self.y)

    self.canvasName.after(100, self.motion)

def move_up(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = -5
def move_down(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 5
def move_left(self):
    self.x = -5
    self.y = 0
def move_right(self):
    self.x = 5
    self.y = 0
```

It might be something dumb but I am still pretty new at this. Thanks.

Comment: there seem to be other issues for example with bindings: `root.bind("<KeyPress-Left>",m.move_left())` take this for example, first of this will get executed immediately so You should use `root.bind("<KeyPress-Left>",m.move_left)` however in this case it will still throw an error since `.bind` passes an event argument so that should be handled for example like this: `root.bind("<KeyPress-Left>", lambda e: m.move_left())` also per PEP 8 class names should be `CapitalCase` oh and those You call circle and line objects are not objects (technically they are but..) they are integers

Comment: Your `self.lines` attribute is None, since `create_lines()` didn't return anything.

Comment: Please try to [edit]  your question to include a single block of code which contains a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. The problem was that my `create_lines` function did not return anything. Also me not using lambda in `.bind`.